# Build Java code using Python

Tags: java, python

Pretendo criar um script python que dado um nome de uma função JAVA procura-a numa biblioteca e copia-a para outro ficheiro.
Há alguma maneira de procurar funções JAVA (fornecendo o nome) sem fazermos o search string-a-string?

Answer (score 0):

String a string "wont cut it" - você vai ter que criar um parser minimalista - possivelmente possa até fazer uma expressão regular - que leia o arquivo, ache s declarações de métodos, as linhas de início e de fim (para isso, basta contar o balanço de "{" e "}" - e recortar esse trecho do texto.

Eu leria o arquivo todo e faria um loop misto: pegando ao mesmo tempo toda uma linha (olhando para frente no texto até o próximo "{") para achar declarações de classe e de método, e um loop caractere por caractere, mantendo informações de estado para contar quantas chaves ("{") foram abertas e quantas fechadas.

Dentro de uma classe, em qualquer linha com zero chaves abertas em que você tenha um "(" e não tenha um sinal de "=" você está na declaração de um método - ai vocẽ pode usar o métodoo split mesmo para ter o nome do método.

Dependendo do que mais precisar fazer, pode tentar esa abordagem, ouprocurar por "java parsers'em Python -- uma busca rápida no Pypi retornou esse aqui: 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/javalang/0.10.2  - veja a documentação dele e se ele já faz o que você precisa.